# C# One type to represent multiple types (including generics)

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, event-handling

Our monolithic WinForm application is getting a face lift.  One current challenge that we are restructuring how we setup events.  I rolled my own event manager class to handle the subscriptions and unsubscriptions to prevent leaks whenever developers write code.

I ran into several challenges with storing generic values in non-generic types.  So I came up with a pattern that allowed me to do it.  Not sure if I am creating a code smell while doing it so I wanted someone to review and ask questions.

**Base View**

```
public abstract class View : Form, IView
{
    protected readonly EventManager EventManager;

    public View()
    {
        EventManager = new EventManager(this);
    }

    protected abstract void RegisterEvents();
}
```

**Concrete Class**

```
public class MyView : View
{
    protected override void RegisterEvents()
    {
        EventManager.Attach(button1_Click, handler => button1.Click += handler, button1.Click -= handler); 
    }
}
```

**Event Viewer**

```
public class EventManager : IDisposable
{
    private IList<TrackedEvent> Events = new List<TrackedEvent>();
    private IDisposable Owner;

    public EventManager(IDisposable owner)
    {
        Owner = owner;
    }

    public void Attach<TEventArgs>(EventHandler<TEventArgs> handler, Action<EventHandler<TEventArgs>> addEvent, Action<EventHandler<TEventArgs>> removeEvent = null)
    {
        Events.Add(GenericTrackedEvent<TEventArgs>.Register(@delegate, handler.Method.Name, removeEvent));            
    }
            
    public void Attach(EventHandler handler, Action<EventHandler> addEvent, Action<EventHandler> removeEvent = null)
    {           
        Events.Add(TrackedEvent.Register(@delegate, handler.Method.Name, removeEvent));           
    }

    public void Dispose() { ... }

    private class TrackedEvent : IDisposable
    {
        protected EventHandler Handler { get; set; }
        protected string MethodName { get; set; }
        protected Action<EventHandler> Unsubscription { get; set; }

        protected TrackedEvent() { }

        private TrackedEvent(EventHandler handler, string methodName, Action<EventHandler> removeEvent)
        {
            Handler = handler;
            MethodName = methodName;
            Unsubscription = removeEvent;
        }

        internal virtual void Remove()
        {
            Unsubscription(Handler);
        }

        internal static TrackedEvent Register(EventHandler handler, string methodName, Action<EventHandler> removeEvent)
        {
            return new TrackedEvent(handler, methodName, removeEvent);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Handler = null;
            Unsubscription = null;
        }
    }

    private class GenericTrackedEvent<T> : TrackedEvent
    {
        protected new EventHandler<T> Handler { get; private set; }
        protected new Action<EventHandler<T>> Unsubscription { get; private set; }

        internal override void Remove()
        {
            Unsubscription(Handler);
        }

        private GenericTrackedEvent(EventHandler<T> handler, string methodName, Action<EventHandler<T>> removeEvent)
        {
            Handler = handler;
            MethodName = methodName;
            Unsubscription = removeEvent;
        }

        internal static TrackedEvent Register(EventHandler<T> handler, string methodName, Action<EventHandler<T>> removeEvent)
        {
            return new GenericTrackedEvent<T>(handler, methodName, removeEvent);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            Handler = null;
            Unsubscription = null;

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

So several things to point out and as to why:

1. **Some methods have been shortened for brevity.**
2. TrackedEvent holds onto the unsubscription e.g: the removeEvent handler.
3. Previously implementations I struggled with storing generic types in a non-generic class without constant boxing/unboxing.
4. The two static methods "Register" will return a TrackedEvent class because its constructors are private.  I don't want anyone creating one outside of my implementation.
5. TrackedEvent only handles non-generics.
6. GenericTrackedEvent handles generics by hiding our base properties and overriding key properties.
7. Unexpectedly, inheritance is working correctly when calling the remove method.  My initial expectation was the GenericTrackedEvent was going to use the underlying TrackedEvent.Unsubscription and TrackedEvent.Handler properties but I was wrong - and that was okay.
8. Someone is going to ask - why are you passing over the MethodName?  Because I actually wrap my handlers in a new delegate so I can capture when event fire and log them to any source I choose.  When I wrap my delegates in the attach method it carries that name over instead of the original one passed in the handler parameter.  Instead of masking that method, I figured I'd keep it.  Again some code was remove because I do not deem it relevant to the initial question.

Seems like we've implemented a duck typing but its usage is abstracted away from developers so I think its okay but wanted several other opinions to weight in.

Thoughts?

Comment: The `View` and `MyView` classes are somehow 'lazy' clases (according to what you are showing us) however if in the future they will contain and provide more operations then it isn't a bad design.

Comment: You should correct the names: Neither `TrackedEvent.Register`, `GenericTrackedEvent<TEventArgs>.Register` nor `@delegate` exists.

Comment: @Henrik right - sorry had some last minute edits before writing this.

Comment: @HenrikHansen furthermore, `@delegate` does exist in the full implementation.  I wrap the original handler with logging so we can track the usage of the event for debugging purposes  Doing this causes the new delegate's `MethodName` to attach itself to that class, instead of the original handler.


`void @delegate(object s, TEventArgs e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"\t{Owner.GetType()} event {handler.Method.Name}<{typeof(TEventArgs)}> has fired with {e}...");

                handler(s, e);
            }`

Comment: Why the duplicate code, when the generic version can just be passed `EventArgs.Empty` if there isn't any event data?

Comment: @tinstaafl At the time, I didn't realize that EventHandler is actually equal to EventHandler<EventArgs>.  Knowing that this can easily be simplified, thanks!

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question after receiving answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. It simply gets too messy if we'd allow it. Feel free to ask a follow-up question instead and to add links to both questions back-and-forth.

Comment: @mast Fair enough - but then how do others learn of the solution that was derived from the review?

Comment: You can write a self-answer, as long as it reviews the code provided. Code-only answers are not reviews. If the points in those review are already made by other reviewers, please state so in the answer. Perhaps making it community-wiki and adding links in that answer would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would question what you intend with this system. In my personal experience, when someone writes something like this it's because they have no actual work assigned to them, but don't want their managers to realize that.

Take a step back and ask yourself what is the improvement you gain from:

1. Requiring an additional class to be present in every form inheritance tree.
2. Making it so user controls aren't handled by this system (from the inside I mean, since your base class derives from `Form`).
3. Requiring a manual line of code to handle creation and removal of events in one specific function (what if I want to add a handler at run-time? What if I want to use post-2002 lambda expressions instead of 6 lines of code for a simple handler? What if I want to use the designer, which handles renaming for me?)
4. I don't think you even considered early event removal.

You say you want to avoid forgetting to remove event handlers. Any properly written handler doesn't need to be removed, only handlers that strongly root the form object require this (and in this case it's not a memory leak exactly, it's your form not closing). And this system doesn't solve strong rooting, since it stores a non-weak-referenced list of these unsubscribe handlers, which reference your form, thus rooting the form in your object. You're literally creating the problem you're claiming to solve (refer back to my first statement).

You don't show this, but what triggers the unsubscribe? The form's own dispose call? I hope not, because that won't trigger in a problem scenario with this code, and the fact that you mark this "manager" as `IDisposable` worries me greatly. The `FormClosing` event? I hope not, because that would prevent close cancellation. Yet another manual call to something? I hope not, because you're supposedly trying to automate ..something, not throw in more manual calls that always have to happen or BOOM.

As to the actual code presented, it's not much, but at the very least write a bit of smart code to handle subscribing and unsubscribing automatically from a handle to the event and handler. You have expressions to parse code provided to your function and generate changed executable code from it, and you have code emitting, between those two you should be able to call your function like this at least:

```
EventManager.Attach(button1_Click, button1.Click);
```

Edit: Oh god I just noticed your `new` field modifier. Use proper OOP and you won't need a `GenericTrackedEvent<T>` that's literally twice as large as the thing it "derives" from, since it has the previous fields as well as the `new` ones. And at the very least don't mark them `protected`, there's no reason for that.

Comment: You cannot pass an event handler as you suggested.  You'll receive an error that events can only be assigned on the left hand side of the operator.  That was my first approach but it doesn't work.  Playing devils advocate - maybe I missed something.  How did you get that to work?

Comment: It's one thing to ask how it's done, it's another to absolutely say "you cannot do this". I didn't implement this because it's rather trivial, but here you go, event attachment by reference: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9RLRsN. I trust you can do the unsubscription yourself from this, but if not feel free to ask (though Stack Overflow is really the place to ask *how* to do things, this is just code review).

Comment: I probably didn't explain it correctly - trying to do this on an event in the same class works, but on a control's event does not.  I should have cleared that part up.  Expanding on your current suggestion to show the problem:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7L9wcV

That's why I suggested that it couldn't be done.

Comment: Still doable with very minimal changes: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zZ0R0W

Comment: When I went down that path I didn't like the fact I had to pass in a string for the event name.  Either it had a raw string so no direct reference to the event or the nameof expression which felt too clunky.  So I was eager to find a solution without either.

Then I was met with another impass.  Either forego the control reference, or just accept the EventHandler/Delegate.  As you already know, I went with the latter.

Based on your feedback and several others, I went ahead and refactored the EventManager with more OOP's and features.  I'll post it here shortly.

Comment: The pros of this method are that 1. you don't need to always specify `+=` and `-=` with the same code, 2. you don't need to have an external function handler, you can use lambas, as in my code, 3. while `nameof` is not ideal, it is checked at compile time so it's always correct and 4. there's absolutely no repetition in the call (DRY): you specify the object once, the event once and the handler once.

Comment: I suspect there's no reason why I can't provide more overloads to do both.  At the end they funnel into the same internal tracker to unsubscribe them.  So following up on your other previous comment.  This example only shows a form but we allow it on forms and custom controls for sure.  Next I intended to wire this up in the forms Dispose(bool disposing) method.  You made it seems like a bad idea.  Why?  Other than abrupt unhandled errors - where's the downside?  I read that its recommended.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem you're trying to solve. `Dispose` is called when the form is garbage collected, sometime after it's closed. For it to get to that point naturally, your events have to not root the form (or the GC won't try to clean it), and if it gets to be disposed naturally, then there's no need to remove event handlers, they get automatically removed by the controls' `Dispose` logic (or more accurately cleaned up, since the Win32 API doesn't care about events).

Comment: Might be best to move this to chat.  Till then I checked out the code and close calls dispose directly.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,3563

Comment: So the reason why the push for cleanups is this legacy application runs the entire business.  It is a desktop level application that sits in front of our staff on the counter checking out customers or working with backend staff.  They open and close hundreds of different forms each day and may not recycle the application for days/weeks/months.

Comment: @Blindy Just a note for any future answers that you may provide: Being overwhelming condescending to the OP is not helpful and does not make you look more intelligent.

Thank you and good day.

Answer (score -4):

Look into the C# **dynamic** type which indicates that the variables type can change at runtime.

For example,

```
dynamic event= "get_credentials";
...
event= 5;
...
event= someFunction;
```